# In Word 2016, I want to make the first level of a Multi-Level list horizontally centered in margins, but the rest of the levels be left aligned

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using Heading 6 through 9 for Appendix headings.  I've created a multi-level list so that I have Level 1 being Appendix A, B, C. etc.  (Each as title text also.)  Level 2 is A.1, A.2; B.1, B.2; etc.  I want the Level 1 (Appendix A Acronyms, for example) to be centered in the margin, but have Level 2, etc. be left aligned.

No matter what I choose on the Multi-Level screen for Level 1, it doesn't center.  I even have the properties for Heading 6 as centered.

Comment: Update the master template styles so that Level 1 is centered. See https://www.howtogeek.com/399978/how-to-change-heading-styles-in-ms-word/

Answer (score 0):

1. With your desired heading selected, manually center it on the page (Ctrl+E).
2. If you have multiple instances of the heading in your document, in the Style pane, right-click on the heading style and choose "Select All Instance(s)".
3. Again in the Style pane, right click on the heading style, and choose "Update [*your heading name*] to Match Selection".